# Storing Arbitrarily Ordered Heirarchal Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store a list where the users can insert new comments anywhere within the list and have it remain in that same ordering Moving subtrees around should not happen very often. The current UI demo is at http://spencerflem.github.io/.

Having done some research, I have found 2 solutions that seem good in different ways and was wondering which would be most recommended. From what I can tell, the simplest solution of simply storing the parent_id will not work with MySQL as it has no CONNECT BY and would need a much more complicated recursive function. Similarly, nested sets and path enumeration seem to be more complicated to maintain, and have more overhead when adding new items.

The first solution I have found is to use a closure table which stores the path from each comment to each descendant. The breadcrumbs are stored as a comma separated varchar list or the ID's, such that ORDER BY breadcrumbs would sort everything correctly alphabetically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069674/sorting-a-subtree-in-a-closure-table-hierarchical-data-structure This seems far more complicated but more idiomatic.

It wasn't mentioned, but could the IDs have large gaps between such that inserting between would not have to renumber everything? I suspect that would be fine, however I have only ever seen AUTO INCREMENT.

A simpler way would be to merely store the breadcrumbs string, perhaps even as the PRIMARY KEY. This would also return the correct order, but it seems much less idiomatic.

Which solution would you recommend, or is there another one that I have missed? Thanks!

Comment: *"The breadcrumbs are stored as a comma separated varchar list"* I don't see in that answer to say that the breadcrumbs are stored. I see them produced by a query. if they are stored, it's not the closure model. It's closure combined with path enumeration.